# If last number from first group is x then

Tags: excel, if-statement, find

I have a cell `G19` that contains the following `N2640001 Km0,800`

In another cell I want to display `O` or `A` depending on the value of the last number from the first part, in my exemple it's `1` so the value in my other cell should be `O`

If the first part would end in 2 the value needs to be A

Comment: So what is your programming question? Have you tried anything? Read [ask].

Comment: Build up your `IF` statement in steps. Start out by figuring out how to determine what the last character of the leading block of text is. As a hint, use `FIND` to locate the position of the `space` character, then extract it so you can test it with an `IF` statement. Use the `MID` formula like this: `MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)-1,1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below will do what you want, although I was unsure what any value other than "1" or "2" should have so I have a catch all of "other";

```
    =IF(MID(G19,FIND(" ",G19)-1,1)="1","O",IF(MID(G19,FIND(" ",G19)-1,1)="2","A","Other"))
```

.

Just to clarify what is being done here for anyone new to excel formula;

What this does is looks for the position of the 1st space in cell G19 `FIND(" ",G19)<`

This starting point `-1` is then used as the starting point of the `MID` extraction. so we are now looking at the last digit before the 1st space and the `MID` states that we want only the 1st character (from our new starting point).

In the `IF` we state that if this is `="1"` then we want an `O` to be returned. During the next if we state that if it is `="2"` we want an `A` to be returned.

And finally if neither of these 2 criteria are satisfied then we want the word `"Other"` to be returned.

Comment: no problem, I should have really explained what it is doing but I was in a rush that day. I will edit now with explanation for future users